# How to get activation of a hidden layer in tensorflow.js?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

In TensorFlow.js, I have a very simple `tf.Sequential` model created like this:

```
let model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape: [784], units: 128, activation: 'relu'}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 10}));
model.add(tf.layers.softmax());
```

During prediction time, how can I get the activation of the second `tf.layers.dense` layer?

Can I just delete `model.layers[2]` and use `model.predict()` as normal?

(I know I can do this in advance by defining two model outputs with the functional API, but let's say I have a pre-made `tf.Sequential` model that I want to inspect the logits of.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more complex models, there's an easier way. If `model` is the original model, you can create a copy using `tf.model({inputs:model.inputs, outputs: model.layers[2].output})`, thereby only needing to provide the first and last layer

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this.

Deleting `model.layers[2]` doesn't work, since apparently `model.predict()` doesn't depend on that property.

One way to do this is to create a duplicate `tf.Sequential` model, copying over all the layers (except the last) from the original.

```
let m2 = tf.sequential();
m2.add(model.layers[0]);
m2.add(model.layers[1]);
```

Then `m2.predict()` will output the logits.